# Execute binstub in subprocess

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to execute other gem's binary in my own gem. But somewhy, I got following error at `Gem.bin_path` when I execute `bin/rspec` (rspec here is no meaning. which binstub to execute does not matter)

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:309:in `block in replace_bin_path': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/vagrant/works/test/bundler-problem/chef/bin/knife:16:in `<main>'
```

If I execute directly `chef/bin/knife`, it succeed without failure. I isolated this problem into repository https://github.com/pandora2000/bundler-problem

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I now tried `system(Gem.bin_path(..))`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the link http://www.rakefieldmanual.com/fascicles/001-clean-environment.html and solved the problem with `Bundler.with_clean_env`